# Shisha Ve'arba'im Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred forty-six?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding to [R'Yosef's answer (the number of *p'sukim* in *Miketz*)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/4659): *B'reshis*, too. And *Amos*.

Answer (score 5):

The number of pesukim in Parshas Miketz.

Answer (score 3):

The Siman in Shulchan Aruch with the most Se'ifim is Yorah Deah 331. This Siman has 146 Se'ifim.